Xamarin (Android) : The Disconnect Signal or Output from a Bluetooth barcode scanner (HID) when Disconnecting Intefers with the CollectionView
This is my first question, so I apolgize if any information is missing or it is unclear. This is a Xamarin (Android) related issue. It is a specific issue, so I wanted to thank anyone that tries to help in advance.
We are using a handheld barcode scanner that works similar to a keyboard for an app. It outputs the scanned barcode. It works well in that regards, but when it disconnects due to a time out, it can mess up the collectionview or page the user is currently on. For example, all of the data bindings for a collectionview disappear and the stepper changes to a black colour. This seems to be only for the android part and not IOS to my knowledge.
The disconnect can interfer when a page is loading as well and I think the HID or bluetooth input goes through the UserDialogs loading functionality as it doesn't block it.
For a breakdown of the structure of our code, the interface for the page is IQueryAttributable and a function is called in to load the data for a collectionview. The functionality we need from the barcode scanner is just the output into an entry and we haven't configured anything specific for the bluetooth connection as it wasn't needed.
I'm looking for a way to prevent that disconnect signal or ouput from interferring with other pages on the Android version or some other solution such as limiting the keyboard. For now, we need it for Xamarin, but a solution that works on Maui would be amazing as well.
I tried capturing the keypress input such as keypress up or down for the barcode scanner on the main activity for Android. Perhaps, I didn't capture it correctly, but it did not help my problem as I couldn't stop the event from propogating downwards.
To replicate the problem, if I tried scanning with the barcode scanner while the page is loading, I can sometimes replace the issue. However, I know it happened on a page that was already loaded. I havne't seen this issue on the IOS version and it doesn't really happen when connecting the bluetooth device.
Please let me know if more information is needed or if I can clarify this.

please read [ask] and [mcve] before posting.  You haven't included any relevant code so its impossible to offer any specific advice
